# Where to find a thorough list of node_redis commands?

Tags: redis, socket.io, node-redis

I'm using redis to store the userId as a key and the socketId as the value. What's more important is that the userId doesn't change, but the socketId constantly changes. So I want to edit the socketId value inside redis, but I'm not sure what node_redis command to use. I'm currently just editing by using .set(userId, mostRecentSocketId).

In addition, I haven't found a good node_redis API anywhere with a complete list of commands. I briefly looked at the [redis-commands](https://github.com/NodeRedis/redis-commands) package, but it still doesn't seem to have a full list of complete commands.

Any help is appreciated; thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full list of Redis commands can be found at https://redis.io/commands. After finding a proper command it wouldn't be hard to find how is it proxied in binding ("api") you use.

Upd. To make it clear: you have Redis Server, its commands are listed at the doc I [provided](https://redis.io/commands). Then you have [redis-commands](https://github.com/NodeRedis/redis-commands) - it's a library for working with redis  (I called it a "[binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding)"). My point was that `redis-commands` may have not all the commands that redis-server can handle, and also the names of some commands can differ a bit. Some other bindings can offer slightly different set of commands. So it's better to examine the list of commands that Redis Server handles, and then select a binding that allowes calling that command (I guess all the bindings have `set` method)

Comment: is using .set() the right function to use? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "binding ("api")".

Comment: @Hunter690 Concerning ```set``` - yes, it quite fits the described situation. (Take a look to ```hset```, but as far as I see your case, ```set``` is better). Concerning "binding" - I've updated by answer.